# Set null as default value for the datetime property

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

Can you tell me how to set `null` as default value for the `datetime` property ?

**Code first model :**

```
public class VendorDetail 
    {
       public virtual DateTime? DateReceived { get; set; } 
    }
```

When `null` value comes from the UI,it gives `The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.` error.So my idea is to set a `null` as default value on the above code first model.Hope that will sort out the issue.Any idea ?

**Update :** I have tried as shown below.But it gives the same error.

```
 public virtual DateTime? DateReceived { get; set; } =null;
```

**On SQL Db :**

[image]

**Note :** The assigned value is `null` form the UI.But Ef converts it to `01/01/0001` and tries to insert it to `datetime` column.That is why it gives above run time error. I can sorted out this issue by changing the column type to `datetime2`. But due to business rule where I need to put that value as `null` on the sql table.Can you tell me how to do that ?

Comment: It's probably not nullable in the database. How did you map the property?

Comment: @GertArnold It's `null able` on the db.Please see the image above.

Comment: Then somewhere you assign a value to it that doesn't match the range of the SQL-Server `datetime` data type. You need to show the code that causes the error.

Comment: @GertArnold The assigned value is `null`.But Ef converts it to `01/01/0001` and tries to insert it to `datetime` column.That is why it gives above run time error. I can sorted out this issue by changing the column type to `datetime2`. But due to business rule where I need to put that value as `null` on the sql table.Can you tell me how to do that ?

Comment: No EF will store it as Null if the Db schema is correct. check your code somewhere between the UI and data storing. set break point by savechanged and check it out.

Comment: @GertArnold Yes,you're right. Even though I have correctly mapped the data model,I didn't do it for the `Dto` object.In other words it didn't allow for the `null`.I have corrected it and now it's working.Thanks for the support.

Comment: @BassamAlugili Yes,you're right. Even though I have correctly mapped the data model,I didn't do it for the `Dto` object.In other words it didn't allow for the `null`.I have corrected it and now it's working.Thanks for the support.

Comment: @GertArnold it was your hint post as answer